# Is there a way to send clients or users Logcat or exceptions to me?

Tags: java, android

Hí,

I'm doing my second App, and The second one is a little bit complex, it's backup tool.

In some devices works perfect in others not.

I would like if is there a way to do my own Exceptions catcher to my server or log cats or smth, and receive them, and known if my app needs some fix or not etc.

Greetens and thanks

David

Comment: ACRA, ACRA, ACRA ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, you can use `ACRA`.  The site states:

> Acra catches exceptions, retrieves lots of context data and send them
>   to the backend of your choice.

and that is what you seem to need.  The Quick Setup Guide is there on the homepage itself.

---

You can also look into [BugSense](https://www.bugsense.com/features) which you can use as a back end for your ACRA.

> If you are using ACRA, you can use BugSense as your backend.
>
> The only change you need to do is specify in formUri BugSense's url
>   and your API key:
>
> @ReportsCrashes(formUri =
>   "http://www.bugsense.com/api/acra?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY", formKey="")

Comment: Thanks for yout tip, I'll check the site and guide :-)